# Difference between using subscript syntax and "dot" syntax when accessing attributes of a variable or advantages of usage one of them

Tags: variable, difference, attribute

When to use

```
{{ variable.property }}
```

and when to use

```
{{ variable['property'] }}
```

Is there a difference between these methods of accessing attributes of a variable or advantages of using one of them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They're both the same for the most part.

The only time I'd use the second way you listed is when the property is a variable.

For instance:

```
{% set foo = 'name' %}
{{ variable[foo] }}
```

This will give you `{{ variable.name }}`

Comment: Yes, using property as a variable is definitely important thing! +1

Answer (score 4):

Generally speaking, no. They are just two ways of saying the same thing.

Dot syntax is necessary when you are referring to a **method** within an object. However, if you are only trying to access the **property** of an object (or a value within an array), either technique will work.